# Kotlin-Coroutines multi-launch with supervisor fails

Tags: kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

The list of `Factory`s should be

- executed on the IO Dispatcher
- execute ALL factories even if they crash
- the crash should be recorded somehow (dirty in the test: errorRecord)

For reasons the test fails with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Factory(#2).create(any())) was not called

    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.failIfNotPassed(VerifyingState.kt:66)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:47)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:60)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.VerifyBlockEvaluator.verify(VerifyBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalVerify(API.kt:118)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify(MockK.kt:146)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify$default(MockK.kt:143)
```

Here's the test itself:

```kotlin
import io.mockk.Runs
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.just
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.verify
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import org.junit.Test


@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutineTest {

  @Test
  fun problem() = runBlockingTest {
    val test1 = mockk<Factory> { every { create(any()) } throws IllegalStateException() }
    val test2 = mockk<Factory> { every { create(any()) } just Runs }
    val test3 = mockk<Factory> { every { create(any()) } just Runs }
    val test4 = mockk<Factory> { every { create(any()) } just Runs }

    var errorRecord: Throwable? = null
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, error -> errorRecord = error }

    launch(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler) {
      listOf(test1, test2, test3, test4).forEach {
        launch { it.create("test") }
      }
    }

    verify(exactly = 1) { test1.create(any()) }
    verify(exactly = 1) { test2.create(any()) }
    verify(exactly = 1) { test3.create(any()) }
    verify(exactly = 1) { test4.create(any()) }

    assert(errorRecord != null)

  }

  interface Factory {
    fun create(data: String)
  }
}
```

Sometimes it randomly is successful. (I guess in case test1 is the last call)

Any ideas on this?

Comment: You don't seem to be waiting for the end of your `launch`-ed coroutines before calling `verify`. You probably should switch your top `launch` for `coroutineScope` or `withContext` instead

Comment: Isn't that solved by using `runBlockingTest` ?

Comment: When I did your suggested change, I got: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet`

Comment: `runBlockingTest` only ensures that *when it returns* all coroutines will be finished, but `verify` calls are *within* the block, so no guarantees there

Comment: ^ this may not be true actually. It seems `runBlockingTest` may well enforce immediate dispatch of `launch`, my bad (I haven't used coroutines-test in a while sorry)

Comment: Except launch is explicitly dispatched to `IO`, so `runBlockingTest` is not relevant